# How can I get multi select dropdown box?

Tags: jquery, html

I have two dropdown box. 1st box having list of values. When I click add button the selected value from dropdown1 shift to dropdown2. Then when I click "add all" button all the values from list will shift from dropdown1 to dropdown2 through jQuery. Here I am having problem.

After add the values from box1 to box2 when I click submit button the scrolldown of dropdown is automaticaly scrolling one time then ly values ll be submit. How can I avoid this.
Here they are adding the list of values one by one to another box... how can I avoid this.

For example:

```
var arr =[];
$('#'+selectedValues+' option').each(function (i,option){ arr[i]=$(option).val();
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){ $('#'+selectedID).val(arr);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean when you say "the scrolldown of dropdown is automaticaly scrolling one time then ly values ll be submit."?

Comment: And also some piece of code for better help?

Comment: s  when i click submit button scrolldown of dropdown2 will be scroll one time automaticaly and the values will be submit. i know this was occur because they add the values one by one through array. how can i avoid this...

Comment: I can't comprehend your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin that does this for you...

http://www.jsplugins.com/Scripts/Plugins/View/Jquery-Two-Sided-Multi-Selector/

It converts a select list (multiple) into a two-sided list with options to move items back and forth etc.